# how create code shortcut in php (php trigger)

Tags: php, triggers, shortcut

i just want to know
how i must create code shortcut in php
i see phpfox script its just use:

```
//for get user id
Phpfox::getUserId();
//when user most be logged in 
Phpfox::isUser(true);
//or user must be admin for do this action
Phpfox::isAdmin(true);
//or this for insert query
Phpfox::getLib('database')->query("")
//so i can get user id easy with this simple code
$userid = Phpfox::getUserId();
```

so these are shortcut yes?
for run some codes and return something just like call function
so how can i create something like this?  for call it for get something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you should read about Database Abstraction Layer..

http://pear.php.net/package/DB

Comment: those are just not database shortcut -- i dont know how create something like Phpfox::getUserId in php for do some action in php its just like call a function but in better way

Comment: I don't use Phpfox. However its functions are very similar to ORM: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html For stuff not DB-related, it's just a matter of OOP implementation. Could you make your question clearer and more specific? Phpfox::getUserID(): are you aware that is a call of method getUserId() of class Phpfox

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking talking about [static class methods or functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) or [class constants.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).